# Selecting values from an array not in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have an array of values, (A,B,C,D) and a SQL Server table (`table1`) with a column (`field1`).

What I want to do is construct a query such that each value selected is not found in `table1.field1`.

For example, if A and D are found in `table1.field1` then the only values that would be selected would be B and C.

What would such a query look like?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: are you doing this in c#/vb? or is the list of values also part of the database?

Comment: I am not doing this is C#/vb.    I'm just looking to create a query on a set of values that I have in an Excel spreadsheet.    I want to know which values in the spreadsheet are not in my database and there are lots of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need "pure" T-SQL it's very easy.
Look - to all intents and purposes you just have 2 multitudes:

```
(A,D)
```

and

```
(A,B,C,D)
```

What you want is "all from second, but not from one". Operator EXCEPT is you answer (that is - logical difference of multitudes):

```
USE tempdb
go

CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 char(1))
go
INSERT T1 VALUES ('A')
INSERT T1 VALUES ('D')
go
CREATE TABLE T2 (col2 char(1))
go
INSERT T2 VALUES ('A')
INSERT T2 VALUES ('B')
INSERT T2 VALUES ('C')
INSERT T2 VALUES ('D')

SELECT * FROM T2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM T1
```

Result:

```
col2
B
C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
select field1 from table1 where field1  not in('A','D')
```

If you want something different, Please comment.